# Can someone help me optimize (or at least, make sure I don't hobble) a gunslinger/magus for PFS play?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, pathfinder-society

I'm moderately familiar with D20 games, though moderately new to PF, but I was invited by a friend-of-a-friend to try out PFS this weekend. I popped into my university's game club to read some pathfinder books and saw the Spellslinger in Ultimate Combat and fell in love with the concept: I've always loved playing spellcasters and individuals who use guns in RPGs... only to find out it was illegal for PFS play. Poo. So I searched around and saw some suggestions that I do a multiclass Gunslinger/Magus, specifically a Myrmidarch, and I'd make his race a tiefling. First off, I need to ask if the concept is mechanically sound- following that, I have a few general questions

1. I was thinking of playing first level as a gunslinger and all others as a magus: do you guys agree?
2. What stats would you recommend? Right now I have Str 10, Dex 18, Con 12, Int 18, Wis 12 and Cha 5, is that a good stat spread?
3. For traits, I was thinking of killer and magical lineage-shocking grasp, though I have been considering swapping magical lineage for magical knack (since I'm multiclassing)
4. I was considering grabbing the tiefling racial trait prehensile tail, which allows me to retrieve a small object as a swift action without using my hands. Is there any way I could use this trait to reduce my reload times with firearms? Barring that, do pistols count as small objects for the purposes of this feat? I just had a great idea of wearing a bandolier of pre-loaded pistols and swapping them out using my tail.
5. What gunslinger archetype should I pick- pistolero or musketeer? With only 1 level of gunslinger, I would only be able to fire a musket once every two rounds (musketeer reduces reloading the musket to a standard action from a full round action, so I still wouldn't be able to attack with it, correct?), so is the pistol much better? Could I use a pistol that doubles as a melee weapon (like sword cane pistol or dagger pistol) with spellstrike?

Thanks for your help: And for those who are worried I'm a munchkin, I can assure you I already have a developed backstory for this character concept.

Comment: Asking lots of questions within a question is generally not a good idea; split them into separate questions. Your first question is an opinion question, and on its own would get closed (An aside; think about your favoured class, which is typically your first class - it offers quite the benefit per level). Is your second question asking about specific stat roll allocation, or for a general "ranking" for stat allocation? Your third question isn't a question. Your fourth question would benefit from a listing for the prehensile tail entry. Your fifth question depends on your character concept.

Comment: @Max welcome to the site.  This question doesn't fit our format though - it's super broad (lots of questions) and mostly opinion based ("do you agree?").  What you could do is post a build, post your intended goals for the character, and ask for focused critique.  See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic for our site guidance on build Q's.